# Proper way to install node.js on aws using chef

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, chef-infra

I've done some research but wasn't able to find anything satisfying. We're using chef 11.

And here's what I have for now. FYI: I am very unfamiliar with chef. So I have a gut feeling that I am doing this wrong.

```
execute "Update apt-get" do
  command 'curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -'
end

package 'nodejs' do
  action :upgrade
end
```

It works most of the time. But it fails sometimes.

```
Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
```

[This issue on ubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/1406268) seems to be the culprit.

Question is, is there a better way than running this `curl` command to update `apt-get` so I can install a later version of node.js?

Comment: You are on a default AWS AMI or Ubuntu AMI?

Comment: It's an Ubuntu AMI

Answer (score 1):

I manage some Node.js apps using chef using the following cookbooks: [application](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/application), [application_git](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/application_git), [application_javascript](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/application_javascript)

The recipe goes as follow:

```
include_recipe 'chef-vault'

# provisions system user to run application
user node['project']['application']['user'] do
  system true
  shell '/bin/false'
  manage_home true
end

application node['project']['application']['deploy_path'] do
  # Provision specific Node.js version
  javascript '4.2.4'

  owner node['project']['application']['user']
  group node['project']['application']['user']

  # Download application source from git private repository
  git node['project']['application']['repository'] do
    deploy_key chef_vault_item('project', 'deploy_key')['file-content']
  end

  # install dependencies
  npm_install do
    production false
    user node['project']['application']['user']
    group node['project']['application']['user']
  end

  # Provision service
  javascript_service 'server.js'
end
```

`project` in my recipes is the name of the specific project been deployed.

This recipe has some advantages:

- It runs your project under a specific user account
- Allow specifying a specific Node.js version (in the example is the 4.2.4 Node.js version).
- The cookbook allow multiple install methods (native package, binary, source). Thus making it portable across different OSes.
- Handle the install of project dependencies
- Provide a service registration in a OS specific manner (classical init on some OSes, Systemd on others, etc.)

Comment: Hah, was coming here to plug `poise-javascript` and `application_javascript` and you beat me to it. Well played!